# Android Studio Error Unrecognized Window Socket

Tags: java, android, windows, sockets, gradle

I installed Android Studio and got this error:

> Error:Unrecognized Windows Sockets error: 87: Socket creation failed

Thus the Gradle project sync failed do not know if its connect with the first error.

Comment: Is this an error that occurred during installation, or when executing some code after the installation was completed? In the latter case, please provide the code that caused this. Otherwise, this is probably not a programming question.

Answer (score 0):

I met same problem in my windows 7 OS, at last I fix it by disable all the no-microsoft auto startup services and items! it seems that some software lead to this error!

win+R -> input msconfig